# How to add a suffix (or prefix) to each column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add `_x` suffix to each column name like so:

```
featuresA = myPandasDataFrame.columns.values + '_x'
```

How do I do this? Additionally, if I wanted to add `x_` as a suffix, how would the solution change?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You can use a `list` comprehension:

```
df.columns = [str(col) + '_x' for col in df.columns]
```

There are also built-in methods like [`.add_suffix()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and [`.add_prefix()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 276):

The following is the nicest way to add suffix in my opinion.

```
df = df.add_suffix('_some_suffix')
```

As it is a function that is called on DataFrame and returns DataFrame - you can use it in chain of the calls.

Comment: You can use add_prefix if you want to add a prefix to the names.

Comment: Too bad this can't be mutable (i.e. doesn't have an `inplace=True` parameter option). Otherwise, perfect.

Comment: I think that this is better than the accepted answer in some circumstances, because it can be used in a chain of operations in a single statement, rather than needing its own statement.

Comment: @CaptainLepton when _wouldn't_ this answer be better than the accepted answer

Comment: If the suffix is not a constant. The title talks about suffixes. The post narrows the scope to a single constant suffix, but if we are answering the post title in general terms, then setting the columns via a list comprehension or other iterable is more flexible

Comment: Documentation page: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html

Answer (score 32):

#### **Elegant In-place Concatenation**

If you're trying to modify `df` in-place, then the cheapest (and simplest) option is in-place addition directly on `df.columns` (i.e., using `Index.__iadd__`).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [9, 4, 2, 1], "B": [12, 7, 5, 4]})
df

   A   B
0  9  12
1  4   7
2  2   5
3  1   4
```

```
df.columns += '_some_suffix'
df

   A_some_suffix  B_some_suffix
0              9             12
1              4              7
2              2              5
3              1              4
```

To add a prefix, you would similarly use

```
df.columns = 'some_prefix_' + df.columns
df

   some_prefix_A  some_prefix_B
0              9             12
1              4              7
2              2              5
3              1              4
```

---

Another cheap option is using a list comprehension with `f-string` formatting (available on python3.6+).

```
df.columns = [f'{c}_some_suffix' for c in df]
df

   A_some_suffix  B_some_suffix
0              9             12
1              4              7
2              2              5
3              1              4
```

And for prefix, similarly,

```
df.columns = [f'some_prefix{c}' for c in df]
```

---

#### **Method Chaining**

It is also possible to do add *fixes while method chaining. To add a suffix, use `DataFrame.add_suffix`

```
df.add_suffix('_some_suffix')

   A_some_suffix  B_some_suffix
0              9             12
1              4              7
2              2              5
3              1              4
```

This returns a *copy* of the data. IOW, `df` is not modified.

Adding prefixes is also done with `DataFrame.add_prefix`.

```
df.add_prefix('some_prefix_')

   some_prefix_A  some_prefix_B
0              9             12
1              4              7
2              2              5
3              1              4
```

Which also does not modify `df`.

---

#### Critique of `add_*fix`

These are good methods if you're trying to perform method chaining:

```
df.some_method1().some_method2().add_*fix(...)
```

However, `add_prefix` (and `add_suffix`) creates a copy of the *entire* dataframe, just to modify the headers. If you believe this is wasteful, but still want to chain, you can call `pipe`:

```
def add_suffix(df):
    df.columns += '_some_suffix'
    return df

df.some_method1().some_method2().pipe(add_suffix)
```

Comment: This is elegant! What if you want to add prefix or suffix to a subset of the columns e.g. the columns whose names all contain a common word (like `new` or `old`) instead of every columns? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu I would suggest going with df.rename() instead... Pass a dictionary mapping names to their new names. Then call rename with axis=1. You can also use conditional list comprehension assignment.

Comment: Works only with regular data types as column names, not if your columns are a RangeIndex like for example `df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]]*10)` --> `df.columns`, then you would use `df.add_suffix('_x')`

Comment: you can do `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str) + '_x' ` as my first method shows.

Answer (score 9):

I Know 4 ways to add a suffix (or prefix) to your column's names:

1- `df.columns = [str(col) + '_some_suffix' for col in df.columns]`

or

2- `df.rename(columns= lambda col: col+'_some_suffix')`

or

3- `df.columns += '_some_suffix'` much easiar.

or, the nicest:

3- `df.add_suffix('_some_suffix')`

Comment: Your 2nd method helped me :)

Answer (score 6):

I haven't seen this solution proposed above so adding this to the list:

```
df.columns += '_x'
```

And you can easily adapt for the prefix scenario.

Comment: Best solution for the suffix, though it cannot be used for prefix of course.

Comment: Works only with regular data types in the column names, not if your columns are a RangeIndex like for example `df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]]*10)` --> `df.columns`, then you would use `df.add_suffix('_x')`

Answer (score 6):

#### Using [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(3), 'B': range(4, 7)})
print(df)
   A  B
0  0  4
1  1  5
2  2  6
```

Using `rename` with `axis=1` and string formatting:

```
df.rename('col_{}'.format, axis=1)
# or df.rename(columns='col_{}'.format)

   col_A  col_B
0      0      4
1      1      5
2      2      6
```

To actually overwrite your column names, we can assign the returned values to our `df`:

```
df = df.rename('col_{}'.format, axis=1)
```

or use `inplace=True`:

```
df.rename('col_{}'.format, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: The best answer, by far. It doesn't create a new object, it allows you to format the string however you want with the mapper. And with no extra lines of code (one-liners are my weakness)

Answer (score 1):

Pandas also has a `add_prefix` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and a `add_suffix` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that this is what I would use quite often, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'silverfish': range(3), 'silverspoon': range(4, 7),
                   'goldfish': range(10, 13),'goldilocks':range(17,20)})
```

My way of dynamically renaming:

```
color_list = ['gold','silver']

for i in color_list:
    df[f'color_{i}']=df.filter(like=i).sum(axis=1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'silverfish': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2},
 'silverspoon': {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6},
 'goldfish': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12},
 'goldilocks': {0: 17, 1: 18, 2: 19},
 'color_gold': {0: 135, 1: 145, 2: 155},
 'color_silver': {0: 20, 1: 30, 2: 40}}
```