# Extending the column name in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a data frame which contains 34 rows and 10 columns. I called the data frame "comp" now I did "invcomp = 1/comp", So the values changed but column name will be same. I want to replace or rename my column names, suppose the earlier name of my first column was "Cbm_m" in "comp", now I want to convert it to "Cbm_m_inv" in "invcomp". Extending or adding an extra term in last.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a suffix to each column name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049618/how-to-add-a-suffix-to-each-column-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'add_suffix':

```
invcomp = invcomp.add_suffix('_inv')
```

Setup:

```
invcomp = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(5,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
invcomp = invcomp.add_suffix('_inv')
```

Output:

```
      A_inv     B_inv     C_inv     D_inv     E_inv
0  0.111604  0.016181  0.384071  0.608118  0.944439
1  0.523085  0.139200  0.495815  0.007926  0.183498
2  0.090169  0.357117  0.381938  0.222261  0.788706
3  0.802219  0.002049  0.173157  0.716345  0.182829
4  0.260781  0.376730  0.646595  0.324361  0.345097
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to solve this from last 4 hours. Thanks a ton. Could I have your email or nay social media way of yours, so I can ask my further doubts directly to you. If it is okay with you. Overall Thanks a lot

Comment: can you again help me, I have a data frame with 120 column now, I want to multiply them by each other. It is like generating 2D features,

Comment: Please post this under a new question on Stack Overflow. And, I or someone else will help.you to the best of our knowledge. Thank you. Remember, we are freely volunteering our time, so post a minimal avout to solve your problem with input data and expected ourputs.

Comment: @chrisb Hello I was using this     
 ...: df = df_base.copy()
     ...: for pair in combinations(df.columns, 3):
     ...:     new_col = '*'.join(pair)
     ...:     df[new_col] = df[pair[0]] * df[pair[1]]*df[pair[2]] 
I was trying to muliply dataframe of 204 columns which is suppose to genrate 1394204 columns. But in 2 hours It only genrated 300420. Can shome how I make it faster.